# Qual a melhor forma de saber se uma URL está funcionando?

Tags: php

A algum tempo precisei verificar se uma imagem externa existia para poder mostrá-la, naquele momento utilizei isso:

```
<?php 
$file = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
$position = strpos($file_headers[0], "404");
if ($position == -1) {
    echo "o site está online.";
}    
?>
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma outra forma de se obter o mesmo resultado com php.

Eu não quero saber se a [url](/questions/tagged/url) é de fato uma [url](/questions/tagged/url) quero apenas saber se ela realmente existe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get_headers()](https://www.php.net/get_headers) é realmente o mais apropriado para esse caso, no entanto, além de sua verificação estar errada (você inverteu os argumento de [strpos()](https://www.php.net/strpos)), eu faria a verificação diferente:

```
$headers = @get_headers( $url );

if( $headers !== FALSE && strpos( $headers[ 0 ], '200' ) !== FALSE ) {

    // OK
}
```

Isso porque antes de verificar algo de algum índice do retorno, você deve verificar o próprio retorno em si, evitando-se Notices indesejados.

E apesar de usar o arroba para suprimir o erro não ser uma boa prática, sem um manipulador de erros customizado, ela precisa ser usada.

No entanto, vale salientar que isso não é suficiente para determinar se uma URL aponta para uma imagem.

Para isso, aproveitando que os cabeçalhos form obtidos, basta se existe a entrada **Content-Type** e se nela existe o termo **image**.

Comment: Esse ponto eu acho que deveria ter sido mais claro, o importante pra mim é verificar a URL independente do Content-Type dela, o que que quero mesmo é saber se ela existe ou não

Comment: Sim, sim, apenas aproveitei para complementar, dado o exemplo e mesmo para referência futura de que vir a encontrar essa duplicata.